# Postgres slow to connect

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql

Postgres 9.5 on Ubuntu server. Connecting from a mac over public internet.

Connecting and performing certain operations, like listing table data, takes forever (something like 10-30 seconds).

Postgres is listening on all interfaces (one IP4 and one IP6).

Connecting with SSL and password. (Slow with or without SSL).

I have tried turning log_hostname = off. That didn't help.

Running nslookup  from the server is fast and correct.

How can this be troubleshot?

Comment: Is it fast locally from a prompt? What kind of query times does it report (that should give an indication if the network or the server is slow).

Comment: As mentioned in my own response, this was actually caused by a bad network (DNS) setup.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that it was actually due to a DNS error with multiple IP addresses registered for the same domain.